# TargetedTriggerAction - Unable To Locate Targeted Item

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I am trying to hook up a trigger to a path that changes the RenderTransform of an image. When I run through my behavior code the Target is null. I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

Here is my Behavior:

```
public class CountryZoomBehaviorTarget : TargetedTriggerAction<Image>
{

    private Image _targetedImage { get; set; }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        _targetedImage = this.Target;

        if (null == _targetedImage)
            return;
        else
        {
            _targetedImage.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(AssociatedObject_MouseEnter2);
            _targetedImage.MouseLeave += new MouseEventHandler(AssociatedObject_MouseLeave2);

        }

    }
    // Remove transform from object.
    void AssociatedObject_MouseLeave2(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        ScaleTransform temp = new ScaleTransform();
        _targetedImage.RenderTransform = null;
    }

    // Grow the transform and attach transform to object
    void AssociatedObject_MouseEnter2(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        ScaleTransform temp = new ScaleTransform();
        temp.ScaleX = 1.10;
        temp.ScaleY = 1.10;
        _targetedImage.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);

        _targetedImage.RenderTransform = temp;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        _targetedImage.MouseEnter -= AssociatedObject_MouseEnter2;
        _targetedImage.MouseLeave -= AssociatedObject_MouseLeave2;
    }


    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Here is my XAML:

```
                    <Image Grid.Column="1" Margin="8,49,0,163" Source="Images/NorthAmer.png" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="364" x:Name="NorthAmerica"/>
                <Path Grid.Column="1" Data="M65,155 L11.5,175.5 L39.5,177.5 L84,146.5 L107.5,165.5 L120,211 L113.5,245 L135.5,290 L153.5,303.5 L176.5,312 L209,331.5 L212,327.5 L189.5,306.5 L188,295 L173.5,304.5 L164.5,288.5 L172.5,274.5 L200,276 L205,287 L209.5,265.5 L223.5,254 C223.5,254 252,231 254,229.5 C256,228 259.5,181 259.5,181 L245.5,169 L264.5,166 L271.5,155.5 L253,109 L265,89.5 L278.5,102 L290,106 L294,177 L303,183.5 L312.5,162.5 L347.5,144 L359.5,94 L372.5,77.5 L340,57.5 L308,62.5 L282.5,48 L193,75 L193.5,90.5 L186,94.5 L177.5,90 L167.5,102.5 L176.5,124 L149.5,109 L137,111 L106,86.5 L79,97 L65.5,117.5 L56,141 z" Margin="11.5,48,413.5,162.5" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox">
                    <interaction:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <interaction:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown" >
                    <vm:CountryZoomBehaviorTarget TargetName="NorthAmerica" />
                        </interaction:EventTrigger>
                    </interaction:Interaction.Triggers>
                </Path>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working. The target object can only be accessed when the associated object is loaded.

THis is a great reference: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Behaviors-and-Triggers-in-Silverlight-3.aspx